# Returning an input stream the right way

Tags: java, multithreading, stream, inputstream

I might be off course here but before I do the implementation I want to make sure I understand correctly what I am doing here is the scenario:

Class A is responsible for collecting document information (ID, content, etc...) I loops to collect chunks of documents (configurable) but for the example let's say 10000 documents at a time.

```
public class A{
    private List<Documents> docs = new ArrayList<Documents>

    public InputStream retrieveAllDocuments(){
        // Loop here to retrive the 10000 document chunk.
        while(docs.size() < 10000000){
            List<TrimmedDownDoc> tempList = callSlowApiToRetrieveDoc();
            ExecutorService.call(InnerA);
        }


        return an InputStream;
    }

    private class InnerA implements Callable<Boolean> {
         private List<TrimmedDownDoc> tempList

         public InnerA(List<...> tempList){
             this.tempList = tempList;
         }

         public Boolean call() {
             // extract temp list and populate docs list in a threadsafe manner.

             // Once this is done I would like to push them to the stream
         }
    }
}
```

I am looking at the best approach so the consumer of class A can read from the stream documents as they become available. This would prevent class A from building a list of documents that would be millions of documents long affecting memory usage. Currently I do not really see alternatives other than saving to a temporary file but I would like to avoid that if possible by just using the right Java object/stream.

Thanks,

Comment: You don’t need a file to create an input stream. But currently your question is way to fuzzy to say anything about it. How do the documents become an `InputStream` or how does the list of documents become a single `InputStream`? And why? The `InputStream` will most likely be read and converted to something that you could create out of your document objects directly instead, so why the detour?

Answer (score 0):

I could be off-base, but might it be best to use an Observer/Subscriber pattern in this case? If you did that, you could return each document that is ready to the subscriber when it's ready and not worry with building a List of any kind at all. If the caller wants a List or to store some document, it's up to the caller. Otherwise, you just go get the next document and let the subscriber worry with whatever it wants to worry with.